# Accessing the state of a Python Multiprocessing.Process subclass from the parent process

Tags: python, parallel-processing, network-programming, multiprocessing

I am creating a simple TCP server as a stub so I can test a script that operates a piece of test equipment, without having to have the equipment there. The server should sit there waiting for a connection and then maintain and update a state variable (just a list of 6 integers) in response to commands that it receives. The parent process (a unit test class for example) should then be able to interrogate the state at any time.

The interface of the server should be as simple as:

```
server = StubServer()
server.start()
'''
the client script connects with the server and
some stuff happens to change the state
'''
newState = server.getState() # newState = [93,93,93,3,3,45] for example
server.terminate()
```

I have subclassed Multiprocessing.Process to do this and I can start the server off no problem. When I first tested this, in the getState() method I just returned the instance variable _state but I found this was always just the initial state. After some digging I couldn't find any similar examples out there. Lots about subclassing Process, but not this specific problem. Eventually I put together the below which uses an internal Queue() to store the state on but this looks messy and clunky to me. Is there a better way to do this?

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class StubServer(Process):

    _port = 4001
    _addr = '' # all addresses 0.0.0.0
    _sock = None
    _state = []
    _queue = None

    def __init__(self, initState=[93,93,93,93,93,93]):
        super(StubServer, self).__init__()
        self._queue = Queue()
        self._state = initState

    def run(self):
        # Put the state into the queue
        self._queue.put(self._state)
        self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._sock.bind((self._addr, self._port))
        self._sock.listen(1)

        waitingForConnection = True
        '''
        Main loop will continue until the connection is terminated. if a connection is closed, the loop returns
        to the start and waits for a new connection. This means multiple tests can be run with the same server
        '''
        while 1:
            # Wait for a connection, or go back and wait for a new message (if a connection already exists)
            if waitingForConnection:
                waitingForConnection = False
                conn, addr = self._sock.accept()
            chunk = ''
            chunks = []
            while '\x03' not in chunk: # '\x03' is terminating character for a message
                chunk = conn.recv(8192)
                if not chunk: # Connection terminated, start the loop again and wait for a new connection
                    waitingForConnection = True
                    break
                chunks.append(chunk)
            message = ''.join(chunks)
            # Now do some stuff to parse the message, and update the state if we received a command
            if isACommand(message):
                _updateState(message)
        conn.close()
        return

    def getState(self):
        # This is called from the parent process, so return the object on the queue
        state = self._queue.get()
        # But put the state back in the queue again so it's there if this method is called again before a state update
        self._queue.put(state)
        return state

    def _updateState(self, message):
        # Do some stuff to figure out what to update then update the state
        self._state[updatedElementIndex] = updatedValue
        # Now empty the queue and put the new state in the queue
        while not self._queue.empty():
            self._queue.get()
        self._queue.put(self._state)
        return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its name implies, `multiprocessing` uses different processes. At some point, [`fork()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) is called and the child processes copy the memory of the parent process, and the child is left with its own memory, not being shared with the parent process.

Unfortunately, you *have* to use [tools available](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) to share memory between processes, leading to the code overhead you mention.

You can look up for other ways to do parallel processing with shared memory, but do mind that sharing memory between threads/processes/nodes/etc is never easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump state of your stub server to file and read it from unittests in any moment. It's pretty simple solution for test needs.

All that you need to do:

- Pass `filename` as parameter to constructor
- Call `_updateState` with init values
- Rewrite `_updateState` to write state to `filename`. It's better to create a new file near `filename` and replace it. If you are worrying about atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Felipe, my question was mainly 'is there a better way than using queues' as I did in the question. After a bit more research (prompted by your mention of shared memory) I have found a shared array is much better for this case:

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Array

class StubServer(Process):

    _port = 4001
    _addr = '' # all addresses 0.0.0.0
    _sock = None
    _state = None
    _queue = None

    def __init__(self, initState=[93,93,93,93,93,93]):
        super(StubServer, self).__init__()
        self._state = Array('i', initState) # Is always a 6 element array

    def run(self):
        self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self._sock.bind((self._addr, self._port))
        self._sock.listen(1)

        waitingForConnection = True
        '''
        Main loop will continue until process is terminated. if a connection is closed, the loop returns
        to the start and waits for a new connection. This means multiple tests can be run with the same server
        '''
        while 1:
            # Wait for a connection, or go back and wait for a new message (if a connection already exists)
            if waitingForConnection:
                waitingForConnection = False
                conn, addr = self._sock.accept()
            chunk = ''
            chunks = []
            while '\x03' not in chunk: # '\x03' is terminating character for a message
                chunk = conn.recv(8192)
                if not chunk: # Connection terminated, start the loop again and wait for a new connection
                    waitingForConnection = True
                    break
                chunks.append(chunk)
            message = ''.join(chunks)
            # Now do some stuff to parse the message, and update the state if we received a command
            if isACommand(message):
                _updateState(message)
        conn.close()
        return

    def getState(self):
        # Aquire the lock return the contents of the shared array
        with self._state.get_lock():
            return self._state[:6] # This is OK because we know it is always a 6 element array
        return state

    def _updateState(self, message):
        # Do some stuff to figure out what to update then..
        # Aquire the lock and update the appropriate element in the shared array
        with self._state.get_lock():
            self._state[updatedElementIndex] = updatedValue
        return
```

This works a treat and is a bit more elegant. Thanks for your help